# Как не перенагрузить сервер большим количеством запросов?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, socket.io

Представим некую абстрактную страницу, на которой через AJAX, путем запроса к API на PHP выполняются запросы к БД. Обновлять данные необходимо 1 раз в секунду, 3600 раз в час. Если страница будет открыта хотя бы у 50 пользователей, мы получим 180 000 запросов в час, не положит ли это сервер, и какие есть еще варианты обновления данных, помимо ajax и socket.io?

Comment: Давайте начнём с очевидного вопроса: почему требуется обновлять данные 1 раз в секунду?

Comment: А почему именно аякс? Почему не сокет и чем не устроил сокет?

Comment: @andreyma, данные постоянно добавляются, соответственно необходимо это обновление показать.

Comment: @And, не хочется тянуть весь Node JS из за одного лишь сокета

Comment: @roudhope данные обновляются каждую секунду? Что за данные такие?

Comment: А причем тут `nodeJS`, `php` довольно не плохо справляется. А в любом современном браузере давным, давно уже есть прокладка `WebSocket`.

Comment: @andreymal заказы в ресторане, добавляются по 3-4 в минуту. Данные не обновляются каждую секунду, нужно проверять наличие их обновления каждую секунду

Comment: @roudhope если три-четыре в минуту, то websocket или server sent events потянут хоть тысячи пользователей без проблем, а тащить ajax сюда не надо

Comment: @andreymal есть ли ссылочки почитать про SSE на пхп с точки зрения нагрузки и съедаемых ресурсов (в т.ч. по сравнению с аяксом)? что-то толком не ищется ничего. Получается на каждого клиента будет висеть пхп-процесс, что в целом весьма требовательно к памяти выходит ведь?

Comment: @teran если для php до сих пор не завезли нормальных однопроцессных серверов, то что ж, могу только посочувствовать, в нормальных языках программирования такого бреда нет :)

Comment: @andreymal не так выразился. имелось в виду сравнение расходования памяти при создании множества новых коннектов при обычном поллинге, и расходы на поддержание работы множества висячих скриптов для sse. пхп процессов естественно будет не на каждого клиента.

Comment: @teran это не ко мне, php не пользуюсь. На Python же тысяча одновременных соединений с Хабра к моему серверу никак не ощущались вообще

Comment: Тут много переменных, выбрать что-то и протестировать, самое узкое место - база

Comment: И с обновлением в одну секунду - перебор

Comment: @teran, `SSE` не подойдет для тысячных клиентов, так-как, не постоянный и односторонний и скорее всего будет переподключаться, что и начнет плодить процессы, которые будут просто не успевать отваливаться по таймауту.